# Confused about average and mean of log-normal distribution, related to orders of permutations

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, permutations, normal-distribution

The paper [The Average Order of a Permutation](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v5i1r41/pdf) starts with

> For $\sigma \in S_n$ let $N(\sigma)$ be the order of $\sigma$ in the group $S_n$. Erdös and Turan showed that if one chooses a permutation uniformly at random from $S_n$ then for $n$ large $\log N(\sigma)$ is asymptotically normal with mean $(\log^2  n) / 2$ and variance $(\log^3 n)/3$. Define the average order of an element of $S_n$ to be
> $$
>  \mu_n = \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} N(\sigma).
> $$
> It turns out that $\log \mu_n$ is much larger than $(\log^2 n)/2$ [...] that $\log \mu_n \sim C\sqrt{n / \log n}$.

This confuses me. As $N(\sigma)$ is (for large $n$) approximately [log-normally distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) with $\mu = (\log^2 n)/2$ and $v = (\log^3 n) / 3$, it has mean
$$
 \exp\left(\mu + \frac{v}{2}\right).
$$
I would guess that this implies that $\mu_n$ equals approximately this mean, as the average converges to the mean? But this is not stated. Can someone please point out what is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Since $\sigma$ is a permutation. It is probably better to write $v=(\log^3n)/3\,.$
I agree that $\mu_n$ should approximately equal
$$
\exp\left(\mu+\frac{v}{2}\right)\,.
$$
The author says that $\log\mu_n$ is much larger than $\mu=(\log^2n)/2$ which seems not confusing because of the extra term $v/2\,.$

Comment: Oh yes, of course $\sigma$ should not be used twice here. There are a bunch of papers on the average order out there. This suggests that it is not that simple... this is what I am asking for, why this "simple argument" is wrong...

Comment: To see that $\log\mu_n$ is much larger than $\mu$ is simple, isn't it? That it is asymptotically $C\sqrt{n/\log n}$ is -as the author writes- the contribution of Erdös and Turan. I am new to this. So can't say more.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I see $exp(\mu + v/2)$ is asymptotically not equal to $C\sqrt{n / \log n}$...

Comment: The author claims that $\log\mu_n=\log\exp(\mu+v/2)=\mu+v/2$ is aymptotically equal to $C\sqrt{n/\log n}.$ With $C=6.4$ I get good matches in python for $n=100,1000,2000$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, of course! So, everything is correct?

Comment: Reading @joriki's answer it sounds like one should now dive into Erdös & Turan's paper to see what exactly assymptotically normal means and in what sense the lognormal distribution has the mean $\exp(\mu+v/2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part that you left out is relevant: “It turns out that $\log\mu_n$ is much larger than $\left(\log^2n\right)/2$, being dominated by the contribution of a relatively small number of permutations of very high order.”

Your argument assumes that taking the limit of the distribution and taking the mean commute, but that need not be the case. For instance, the random variables $X_n$ that take the value $0$ with probability $1-\frac1n$ and the value $n$ with probability $\frac1n$ [converge in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution) to the constant $0$, but their mean is $1$ (and thus converges to $1$). Like in the case of the permutations, this is because of a small probability for high values.